# SQL JOIN and UNION Combined

Tags: sql, join, union

I want to connect my for tables (picture below)
When I use the first and second code all works but i do not have all data that i need.

> 

FIRST CODE WORKS

```
SELECT *
FROM Erste.dbo.Persons1$ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Erste.dbo.Adresses1$ 
ON Erste.dbo.Persons1$.Id=Erste.dbo.Adresses1$.Id 
--LEFT OUTER JOIN Erste.dbo.Adresses2$
--ON Erste.dbo.Persons1$.Id=Erste.dbo.Adresses2$.Id
UNION
SELECT * 
From Erste.dbo.Persons2$
LEFT OUTER JOIN Erste.dbo.Adresses2$
ON Erste.dbo.Persons2$.Id=Erste.dbo.Adresses2$.Id
```

SECOND CODE WORKS

```
SELECT *
FROM Erste.dbo.Persons1$ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Erste.dbo.Adresses1$ 
ON Erste.dbo.Persons1$.Id=Erste.dbo.Adresses1$.Id 
--LEFT OUTER JOIN Erste.dbo.Adresses2$
--ON Erste.dbo.Persons1$.Id=Erste.dbo.Adresses2$.Id
UNION
SELECT * 
From Erste.dbo.Persons2$
LEFT OUTER JOIN Erste.dbo.Adresses2$
ON Erste.dbo.Persons2$.Id=Erste.dbo.Adresses2$.Id
```

First SELECT combined don't work

```
SELECT *
FROM Erste.dbo.Persons1$ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Erste.dbo.Adresses1$ 
ON Erste.dbo.Persons1$.Id=Erste.dbo.Adresses1$.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Erste.dbo.Adresses2$
ON Erste.dbo.Persons1$.Id=Erste.dbo.Adresses2$.Id
UNION
SELECT * 
From Erste.dbo.Persons2$
LEFT OUTER JOIN Erste.dbo.Adresses2$
ON Erste.dbo.Persons2$.Id=Erste.dbo.Adresses2$.Id
```

Error:
Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Completion time: 2024-02-27T18:25:24.6084257+01:00

[Tables and my code from SQL Server Managment Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAVbK.png)

I'm trying to combine these 4 tables.
Can You help me?

Comment: By adding a join in your first query of the union, you added many more columns which don't appear in the 2nd query of the union (the select * adds all columns from all tables).    Erste.dbo.adressees1$ columns do not exist in the 2nd query; thus is your problem. The top query and the bottom query of the union have to have the same number of columns, in the same order and of the same type.  If you know the columns in adresses2$ are 5 in number, you could do `select *, Null, null,null,null,null...` in the 2nd query (after union) to get results.  Better yet, list only the fields you need.

Comment: Run each query on it's own w/o the union.  Count the columns in each.  A union only works if the column count of each query match with teh same data type of every column (top and bottom query)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much xQbert for the help.
I did it in this way.

```
SELECT FirstName, SecondName, Ulica, Numer
FROM Erste.dbo.Persons1$, Erste.dbo.Adresses1$
WHERE Erste.dbo.Persons1$.ID=Erste.dbo.Adresses1$.ID
UNION
SELECT FirstName, SecondName, Ulica, Numer
FROM Erste.dbo.Persons1$, Erste.dbo.Adresses2$ 
WHERE Erste.dbo.Persons1$.ID=Erste.dbo.Adresses2$.ID
UNION
SELECT FirstName, SecondName, Ulica, Numer
FROM Erste.dbo.Persons2$, Erste.dbo.Adresses2$ 
WHERE Erste.dbo.Persons2$.ID=Erste.dbo.Adresses2$.ID
ORDER BY Numer ASC
```

Comment: You're allowed to accept your own answer's.  I'd encourage you to do that here if it's giving you the desired results. Note if the same "record" would exist in multiple data sets the union is doing a distinct.  if you want to keep all the records, you may want to do a `UNION ALL` instead of union.  But that's dependent on your data and expectations.